# TizenTV .NET problem with NuGet packages on physical device

Tags: .net, xamarin, tizen

I am developing Tizen .NET Xamarin Forms application for Tizen TV. And I’ve faced with problem recently. This problem is about using third-party libraries in my application. When I install some NuGet packages, I get an error during launching it on physical device. For instance, launching application with added Tizen.TV.UIControls package produces next error:

`[FAIL] TizenTV.UIControls.Forms.dll refers a forbidden assembly directly - libevas.so 1 :(`.

Is there any solution which can be approved by Samsung Apps TV Seller Office when I’ll publish it later?
Is it a mandatory requirement and I have no choice except developing without such NuGet packages?

I read about working for Samsung Partner Company as Partner Developer and getting information about switching off the security verification mechanism (look https://github.com/SamsungDForum/JuvoPlayer/issues/6#issuecomment-547338585). But I am concerned about publishing. Is it just local solution which cannot be published according to security policy of Samsung TV products? If it’s true, maybe anyone knows about other solution?

Regards,
Vitalii

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is from TV product security policy. As you can see FAQs [here](https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/Smart-TV/FAQ/FAQ.html), existing TV product doesn't allow DllImport for security reasons.

However, if I know correctly, this restriction will be removed from the 2021 TV models with Tizen 6.5.

For more information, it would be good to contact the Samsung Apps TV Seller Office.
Thanks!